Can const field of non-const object be const_cast-ed?
It's well known UB to remove constness from real consts
const int i = 0;
const_cast<int&>(i) = 42; // ub

But it's perectly fine to do so, when you deal with a const reference to a non const
int i = 0;
const int &ri = i;
const_cast<int&>(ri) = 42; // ok

cppreference says the following

A const object is

an object whose type is const-qualified, or
a non-mutable subobject of a const object.

Such object cannot be
modified: attempt to do so directly is a compile-time error, and
attempt to do so indirectly (e.g., by modifying the const object
through a reference or pointer to non-const type) results in undefined
behavior.

Is the const field of a non const instance a "const object" or not?
struct Foo {
    const int c = 0;
};

Foo f = {13};
const_cast<int&>(f.c) = 42; // ???



Yes, it's const. Your field is a const int. That's how it was declared, and that's what it is now. The fact that it exists in an object which may have non-const fields as well is irrelevant. As the reference documentation states, attempting to modify that field (either directly or indirectly) is undefined behavior.

It's UB using a const_cast but, as of c++20, it's completely legal to do with std::construct_at.  Note that if anything in the struct is not trivially destructable, you need to destruct it first.
While one can't directly modify the const object, when it's in a class that is not itself const, the object can be modified using placement new or std::construct_at. All references to the const member will now result in the new value. This can also be used to re-seat a reference member inside a class.
This has been made possible by a change in basic.life
#include<memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    const int c = 0;
};
Foo f = { 13 };

int main()
{
    // std::destroy_at(&f);        // not needed since Foo is trivially destructable
    std::construct_at(&f, Foo{ 42 });
    std::cout << f.c << '\n';
}

